# HomeKit simulator: Adding human readable description to custom service characteristic

Tags: ios, homekit

I have added a custom characteristic to a service using the HomeKit Simulator. However when I add it, despite I include the manufactorer description, a UUID is shown instead of the description.

How can I display the description instead?

The first characteristic is a standard one ("On/Off": boolean). The other ones are custom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now the HomeKit Accessory Simulator (1.1) cannot be configured to show manufacturer description, as you want to.

At least in version 1.1 **custom services** can be attached and achieve a corresponding name, that the developer is able to distinguish. Characteristics can still not be named and remains a UUID mess. But as far as I know, this version (1.1) is only rolled out to MFi participants.

[image: Custom Service Creation Wizard 1.1]

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find this confirmation? Is there an official apple doc stating this?

Comment: MFi participants gets brand new information and tools from apple regarding HAP, like the beta versions of HomeKit Accessory Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a manufacturer description to the characteristic.

[image]

Then after you add it will show like this

[image]

In your app, you can check first if there is a manufacturer description like this

```
let manufacturerDescription = characteristic.metadata?.manufacturerDescription
```